# Column name must be either a string or an array. yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, primary-key, insert-update

while I am updating record it display above error.

> message id seems like this  -  1536126282209770000

```
$q = new CDbCriteria(array(
            'condition' =>  'tokenId = :btokenid',
            'params' => array(
                ':btokenid' => $tokenId,
            ),
        ));

        $record = self::model()->find($q);

        $record->messageId = $messageId;
            if (!$record->save()) {
                $_errors = current($record->getErrors());
                throw new Exception($_errors[0]);
            }
```

I added 2 primary keys for table.

> table structure:

[image: table structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding primary keys to table need to flush the cache

To refresh the database cache :
Load all tables of the application in the schema

`Yii::app()->db->schema->getTables()`;

clear the cache of all loaded tables

```
Yii::app()->db->schema->refresh();
```

If you want to refresh only one table, you can also do :

```
Yii::app()->db->schema->getTable('tablename', true);
```

After that It works fine.